# Adding Vector Data - GML format with WFS Transport (possible bug?)

Tags: vector, openlayers-3, gml, web-feature-service

I'm trying to add features to my OpenLayers map, by querying a publicly available WFS server which serves GML data.

```
// initalize the map
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            // OpenLayers public map server
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        // center on Murica
        center: [-10997148, 4569099],
        zoom: 4
    })
});

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// execute this once the remote GML xml document has loaded
xmlhttp.onload = function() {

    console.log("GML XML document retrieved.  executing onload handler:");
    var format = new ol.format.GML3();

    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    console.log("you will see multiple features in the xml: ");
    console.log(xmlDoc);

    // Read and parse all features in XML document
    var features = format.readFeatures(xmlDoc, {
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    console.log("for some reason only a single feature will have been added: ")
    console.log(features);
    console.log("Why is this?");

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: format
        })
    });

    // Add features to the layer's source
    vector.getSource().addFeatures(features);

    map.addLayer(vector);
};

// configure a GET request
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/dnc/wfs/DNC-WORLD/feature/merged?version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=DNC_APPROACH_LIBRARY_BOUNDARIES&srsname=3857",
   true);

// trigger the GET request
xmlhttp.send();
```

Here is a CodePen with the bug demonstrated.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yamOEK

Here you can download it packaged into a single HTML file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6L3fhx8G3H_cmp1d3hHOXNKNHM

I can successfully download an entire feature collection with multiple features into my variable xmlDoc, using a valid typename.  However, when I use format.ReadFeatures(xmlDoc), the OpenLayers GML format parser appears to only be extracting a single feature from the feature collection, whereas it should be extracting many more.

It would be wonderful if someone could take a look and see if they can figure out if I'm doing something stupidly wrong or it's a legitimate bug in OpenLayers3.  Thanks so much for anyone who's able to help!

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/216125/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single feature is added because entire document is read so instead of format.readFeatures(xmlDoc) parse each feature.Here is source code:

```
    var vector;
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [-8197020.761224195,8244563.818176944],
            zoom: 4
        })
    });

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        var format = new ol.format.GML3();
        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: format
            })
        });

        for (var i = 1; i < xmlDoc.children[0].children.length; i++) {
            var features = format.readFeatures(xmlDoc.children[0].children[i], {
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
            });


            features.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            vector.getSource().addFeature(features);
        }

        map.addLayer(vector);
        map.getView().fit(vector.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize())
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://geoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/dnc/wfs/DNC-WORLD/feature/merged?version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=DNC_APPROACH_LIBRARY_BOUNDARIES&srsname=3857",
        true);

    // trigger the GET request
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Here is a CodePen result.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwXrwJ

Comment: IT WORKS PRAISE dev9 GOD OF ALL EPSGs